# Simple but somewhat tricky riddle

Tags: riddle

What's something a rich man needs,
and a poor man doesn't need,
What's greater than God,
and eviler than the devil?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the normal way to word it is "... and a poor man has".

Comment: ...and if you eat it, you die.

Comment: @GlenO I know I put thag there to make it clear.

Comment: But "doesn't need" isn't clearer. A poor man "doesn't need ___" (with the answer replacing the blank) is a nonsensical thing to say, whereas "has ___" makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

> Nothing

Because:

> A rich man needs nothing. A poor man doesn't need nothing (needs everything). Nothing is greater than God. Nothing is eviler than the devil.