# What is “it”? If you eat it, you’ll die

Tags: riddle, word

Ahoy guys, I’ve got a riddle for you:

If you eat it, you’ll die. If you see it, you’re blind.
The poor people have it.

Original content: https://riddlesbrainteasers.com/greater-than-god/

Comment: I’ve made it up myself. (Sorry if other sites have this riddle)

Comment: Heh, I should have just searched this site! [one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5267), [two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/89838), [three](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/33579), [four](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15453), [five](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/35106), [six](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/78462), [seven](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/16653) duplicates or near-duplicates. I'll vote to close as a dupe the main one, as the others provide precedent for near-matches being duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is tricky.  Nothing comes to my mind.

> Understand: "Nothing" comes to my mind.
>
>  Replace 'it' by 'nothing' and you get:  If you eat nothing you die.  etc.